# How to validate a input field connected to a checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, function, checkbox

My problem is I want to save data with details of user then check a checkbox which has individual input fields. I want to check if the input field under the checkbox is not empty. If not, then the form will submit the details and value of the input field under the checkbox.

This is the sample validation of details of the user.

```
if(fname==""){
    $('#fname').removeClass('border-success');
     $('#fname').addClass('border-danger');
      return false;
        }
 else if(region=="-Select-"){
    Swal.fire('Select', "Please select a region",'warning');
    return false;
     }
 else if(province=="-Select-"){
     Swal.fire('Select', "Please select a province",'warning');
     return false;
            }
```

This is what i try to check if the input field is not empty under the selected checkbox

```
if($('#box1').is(':checked')){
   try{
     for(var j=0;j<pnCN.length;j++)
     if ($(pnCN[j]).val()==""||$(qCN[j]).val()=="")throw 'Empty field';
      }
   catch(err){
       Swal.fire('Warning', "Empty Field",'warning'); 
    }
}
```

What's happening is it catches the error but its not preventing the submit btn to send the details of user to the database. If I do if else it will check all the input field that is not checked or selected.

What I want to do is if user selected a specific category on a checkbox then the user entered data to the input field under the checkbox will be save because it is checked. Also I want to check first if that specific field under the checkbox is not empty. Then save the data together to the database.

Comment: why are you `throwing`? just use the same thing as done in the first code block, put `Swal.fire('Warning', "Empty Field",'warning'); ` and `return false;` inside the `if` and remove the `try catch`

Comment: But I tried that then all the field that isn't check become required

Comment: Then please share the `html` and `js` files for this feature

Comment: its okay now. But i cant post the answer because stackoverflow restricted me to post an answer